# WSO2 Ei Proxy service and DS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

How to set property of XML Object payload's to arguments () to call Wso2 ds using CLOB

***Below is my payload which calling WSO2 DS :***

```
 <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/xml"/>
    <property expression="$body/*" name="acclist" scope="default" type="OM"/>
      <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                      <format>
                         <Body>
                            <p_cif>$1</p_cif>
                            <p_acclist>$2</p_acclist>
                         </Body>
                      </format>
                      <args>
                         <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:cif"/>
                         <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:acclist"/>
                      </args>
  </payloadFactory>
```

***Error message of WSO2 DS :***

```
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: _post_getacclist
Current Params: {p_acclist=, p_cif=00021118}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: Error in 'createProcessedPreparedStatement'
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: 0 char of CLOB data cannot be read
```

I think Input Clob parameter(***p_acclist***) is null or empty,

When i convert **$ctx:acclist** to JSON, it is set upin arguments, But XML is not working

I can pass whole $body// it prints properly too, But i need inside element of this XML.

**`Basically i'am calling Data service using Clob(XML object) from Proxy service`**

Comment: Can you try enclosing the $2 argument under CDATA tag? Like, <![CDATA[$2]]>.

Comment: yes it does not work,  CDATA tag dissappears after save proxy

Comment: it only shows when i set expression as $body//
But it is not valid xml, i cannot pass it as clob to procedure

Comment: Can you try enclosing the payload parameter under the following xml tag?  <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$2</text>

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is twofold:

1. the p_acclist element does not contain any kind of value, but more
   xml. This needs to be in a CDATA block
2. A CDATA block in your payload factory won't work like that because the config is also XML. So the CDATA block in your payloadfactory/proxy will be ignored.

You can solve this by building the message using xslt, within the XSLT you can add the CDATA block as follows:

```
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
  <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>     
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
```

You could even pass on your property to the xslt like so:

```
<xslt key="xlsfilereference">
     <property expression="$ctx:acclist" name="acclist">
     </property>
</xslt>
```

And then use it in the xslt as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:param name="acclist"></xsl:param>
      ...
         <Body>
            <p_cif><xsl:value-of select="[path_to_cif_value]"/></p_cif>
            <p_acclist>
               <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="$acclist"/>    
               <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
            </p_acclist>
         </Body>
      ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You might have to use copy-of instead of value-of in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Since the content of the *acclist* is not a valid XML can you try to enclose the elements with the CDATA tags? Please note that we will not be able to use the CDATA tags directly with the payload factory mediator due to its limitations. You can follow the steps below in order to add the CDATA tags.

1. Create a registry resource with the following elements(conf:/test/format.xml).

   `<Body>
          <p_cif>$1</p_cif>
          <p_acclist><![CDATA[$2]]></p_acclist>
       </Body>`
2. Modify the payload factory mediator as follows.

   `<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                   <format key="conf:/test/format.xml"/>
                   <args>
                      <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:cif"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:acclist"/>
                   </args>
                </payloadFactory>`
3. create a file called XMLInputFactory.properties inside `<EI_HOME>`

   Add the following content into the file

   `javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing=false`